# login en python, diccionarios dentro de un diccionario

Tags: python

les comento la idea. estuve tratando de hacer un login con diccionarios dentro de un diccionario desde hace 2 días pero todavía no encuentro la forma. La idea es hacerlo a partir del usuario y contraseña que ingrese el usuario.
Seguro es de lo mas fácil pero todavía ando aprendiendo xdd, espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias :D

```
usuarios = {
        "iperurena": {
            "nombre": "Iñaki",
            "apellido": "Perurena",
            "password": "123123"
    },
        "fmuguruza": {
            "nombre": "Fermín",
            "apellido": "Muguruza",
            "password": "654321"
    },
        "aolaizola": {
            "nombre": "Aimar",
            "apellido": "Olaizola",
            "password": "123456"
    }
 }

User = print(input("Escriba su usuario: "))
Pass = print(input("Escriba su password: ")) 
for clave in usuarios:
    if User in usuarios.keys() and Pass in usuarios.values():
        print("si")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: Cuál es la idea, el nombre de usuario es el nombre del diccionario y la contraseña la llave "password"? Aquí cuales son los nombres de usuario y cuales son las contraseñas?

Comment: Exacto, los usuarios serian iperurena, fmuguruza y aolaizola y sus respectivas contraseñas dentro de los usuarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varios errores:

```
User = print(input("Escriba su usuario: "))
```

Con `input()` obtienes el nombre, y lo pasas a `print`. Este lo imprime y no retorna nada y por tanto `User` queda en `None`

```
for clave in usuarios:
```

No tiene ningún sentido recorrer la lista de usuarios; ya lo tienes en `User`.

```
if User in usuarios.keys() and Pass in usuarios.values():
```

La parte donde comparas `Pass` está mal. La expresión `usuarios.values()` retorna una lista. Esta lista contiene todos los diccionarios:

```
[{'nombre': 'Iñaki', 'apellido': 'Perurena', 'password': '123123'}, {'nombre': 'Fermín', 'apellido': 'Muguruza', 'password': '654321'}, {'nombre': 'Aimar', 'apellido': 'Olaizola', 'password': '123456'}]
```

Lo que necesitas es recuperar el campo `password` del diccionario `usuarios[User]`.

Recomendación: usar `print()` dentro del código para comprobar que estés obteniendo lo que quieres obtener (o usar debug, lo que sea más cómodo).

Este el código correcto:

```
usuarios = {
        "iperurena": {
            "nombre": "Iñaki",
            "apellido": "Perurena",
            "password": "123123"
    },
        "fmuguruza": {
            "nombre": "Fermín",
            "apellido": "Muguruza",
            "password": "654321"
    },
        "aolaizola": {
            "nombre": "Aimar",
            "apellido": "Olaizola",
            "password": "123456"
    }
 }

User = input("Escriba su usuario: ")
Pass = input("Escriba su password: ")
if User in usuarios and Pass == usuarios[User]['password']:
    print("si")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Ohh, ahora ya entendí mucho mejor los conceptos. Muchas gracias!